# PHP - how to return HTML special characters code?

Tags: php, function, return, special-characters

I'm working on function like this one:

```
function foo() {
   return '[ &#61; ]';
}
```

But this returns:

> [ @ ]

And I need:

```
[ &#61; ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `return htmlentities('[ &#61; ]');`

Comment: This works fine, but how to achieve breaks (<br>) now? :)

Comment: It returns? or does it outputs @? The browser converts it automatically.

Comment: I guess this is part of post, or something for WP, you need regular expression, in order to display like you want. Post more info/content.

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities()` since it will return entities that some browsers won't be able to handle.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` instead and make sure your page's encoding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either call `htmlspecialchars` on your string before you output it, or you could simply replace the `&` in your string with a `&amp;`.

Either one will make a browser show `&#61;` instead of `@`.

Comment: Thank you, this &amp; solution is just simply brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning the correct string.

When you view it in an HTML document, it is interpreted as an entity.

My advice would be to encode the response when you display it, eg

```
$foo = foo();
echo htmlspecialchars($foo, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Changing your function's return value will probably cause issues later on when you may not want the encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

or use:

```
return urlencode('[ &#38;#61; ]');
```